# My tic-tac-toe Python game doesn't end when a player wins

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

Good day. I'm currently reading Michael Dawson's book *Python for the Absolute Beginner*. I have this code for Chapter 6 and when I ran the code and got the straight "X" in the board, it won't return the winner. The program continues until all the spaces are mark with either "X" or "O". Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = " "
TIE = "TIE"
NUM_SQUARES = 9

def display_instruct():
    print(
          """
          Welcome to the greatest intellectual challenge of all time: Tic-Tac-Toe.
          This will be a showdown between your human brain and my silicon processor.

          You will make your move known by entering a number, 0 - 8. The number
          will correspond to the board position as illustrated:

                                      0 | 1 | 2
                                     -----------
                                      3 | 4 | 5
                                     -----------
                                      6 | 7 | 8

            Prepare your self, human. The ultimate battle is about to begin. \n
            """)

def ask_yes_no(question):
    response = None
    while response not in ("y", "n"):
        response = input(question).lower()
    return response

def ask_number(question, low, high):
    response = None
    while response not in range(low, high):
        response = int(input(question))
    return response

def pieces():
    go_first = ask_yes_no("Do you require the first move? (y/n): ")
    if go_first == "y":
        print( "\nThen take the first move. You will need it. ")
        human = X
        computer = O
    else:
        print("\nYour bravery will be your undoing... I will go first.")
        computer = X
        human = O
    return computer, human

def new_board():
    board = []
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        board.append(EMPTY)
    return board

def display_board(board):
    print("\n\t", board[0], "|", board[1], "|", board[2])
    print("\t", "---------")
    print("\t", board[3], "|", board[4], "|", board[5])
    print("\t", "---------")
    print("\t", board[6], "|", board[7], "|", board[8], "\n")

def legal_moves(board):
    moves = []
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        if board[square] == EMPTY:
            moves.append(square)
    return moves

def winner(board):
    WAYS_TO_WIN = ((0, 1, 2),
                   (3, 4, 5),
                   (6, 7, 8),
                   (0, 3, 6),
                   (1, 4, 7),
                   (2, 5, 8),
                   (0, 4, 8),
                   (2, 4, 6))

    for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
        if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != EMPTY:
            winner = board[row[0]]
            return winner

        if EMPTY not in board:
            return TIE

        return None

def human_move(board, human):
    """Get human move."""
    legal = legal_moves(board)
    move = None
    while move not in legal:
        move = ask_number("Where will you move? (0 - 8): ", 0, NUM_SQUARES)
        if move not in legal:
            print("\nThat square is already occupied, foolish human. Choose another.\n")
    print("Fine....")
    return move

def computer_move(board, computer, human):
    """Make computer move."""
    #make a copy to work with since function will be changing list.
    board = board[:]
    BEST_MOVES = (4, 0, 2, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7)
    print("I shall take square number")

    # if computer can win, take that move
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = computer
        if winner(board) == computer:
            print(move)
            return move
        board[move] = EMPTY

    # if human can win, block that move
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = human
        if winner(board) == human:
            print(move)
            return move
        # done checking this move, undo it
        board[move] =  EMPTY

    # since no one ca win on next move, pick best open square
    for move in BEST_MOVES:
        if move in legal_moves(board):
            print(move)
            return move

def next_turn(turn):
    if turn == X:
        return 0
    else:
        return X

def congrat_winner(the_winner, computer, human):
    if the_winner != TIE:
        print(the_winner, "won!\n")
    else:
        print("It's a tie!\n")
    if the_winner == computer:
        print("As I predicted, human, I am triumphant once more. \n" \
              "Proof that computers are superior to humans in all regards.\n")

    elif the_winner == human:
        print("No, no! It cannot be! Somehow you tricked me, human. \n" \
              "But never again! I, the computer, so swears it\n!")

    elif the_winner == TIE:
              print("You were most lucky, human, and somehow managed to tie me. \n" \
                    "Celebrate today... for this is the best you will ever achieve.\n")

def main():
    display_instruct()
    computer, human = pieces()
    turn = X
    board = new_board()
    display_board(board)

    while not winner(board):
        if turn == human:
            move = human_move(board, human)
            board[move] = human
        else:
            move = computer_move(board, computer, human)
            board[move] = computer

        display_board(board)
        turn = next_turn(turn)

    the_winner = winner(board)
    congrat_winner(the_winner, computer, human)

main()

input("Press enter to exit")
```

Comment: Good day, Sir! Upvoted for polite English greeting.

Comment: I'm not really confident that this will solve your problem, but you might try changing the line: if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != EMPTY: to: if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] and board[row[0]]!= EMPTY:

Comment: Thank you for all the answers you've given to me. I appreciate it a lot. Hope you all have a good day.

Comment: One last question. About the return None in ways_to_win. If the winner is return, it will not return None right? Why? the return None is inputted last. My understanding is that when "return winner" the program will continue until the last statement of the function which is "return None". Why is the "return winner" won't change into "return winner". Sorry for my english. If you do not understand. I will explain it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function that checks for a win or tie is incorrect. Currently you have this:

```
def winner(board):
    WAYS_TO_WIN = ((0, 1, 2),
                   (3, 4, 5),
                   (6, 7, 8),
                   (0, 3, 6),
                   (1, 4, 7),
                   (2, 5, 8),
                   (0, 4, 8),
                   (2, 4, 6))

    for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
        if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != EMPTY:
            winner = board[row[0]]
            return winner

        if EMPTY not in board:
            return TIE

        return None
```

Notice that `return None` is inside the loop, so you return `None` when the first row fails to match. That's unless the board is full, in which case you correctly return `TIE`, except you could have checked for a full board before trying to match any rows.

We can make the function correct by reindenting `return None` so that it gets executed after the loop. In addition, it makes sense to move the `TIE` check before the loop.

```
def winner(board):
    if EMPTY not in board:
        return TIE

    WAYS_TO_WIN = ((0, 1, 2),
                   (3, 4, 5),
                   (6, 7, 8),
                   (0, 3, 6),
                   (1, 4, 7),
                   (2, 5, 8),
                   (0, 4, 8),
                   (2, 4, 6))

    for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
        if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != EMPTY:
            winner = board[row[0]]
            return winner

    return None
```

Let's review what this function does. We start by checking for a full board. Then we go on to consider the ways to win. If none of them match, we return `None`.

There's one more problem in your code:

```
def next_turn(turn):
    if turn == X:
        return 0
    else:
        return X
```

In order for the later test `if turn == human:` to work correctly in all cases, the value of `turn` must be either `X` or `O`, not `X` or `0`. This is the quick fix:

```
def next_turn(turn):
    if turn == X:
        return O
    else:
        return X
```

The better way to fix this problem is to avoid having a variable named `O`.

Comment: Thank for the very helpful answer Sir. May I ask some questions sir? Where did you learn to program using python? May I ask some tips where I can learn more about python? Especially about classes and Tknter.

Comment: I learned Python by reading [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/) written by Guido van Rossum, the inventor of the language. It includes material about classes. I learned Tkinter from the [Manning book](http://www.manning.com/grayson/).

Comment: ok Thank you. What other books you like to read or the ones who helped you a lot. Thanks!

Comment: The only other book I've read about Python is [by Mark Pilgrim](http://www.diveintopython3.net/). It's very good. I recommend it.

Comment: Thank you sir. One last question. About the return None in ways_to_win. If the winner is return, it will not return None right? Why? the return None is inputted last. My understanding is that when "return winner" the program will continue until the last statement of the function which is "return None". Why is the "return winner" won't change into "return winner". Sorry for my english. If you do not understand. I will explain it again.

Comment: When Python executes `return winner`, it immediately leaves the `winner` function. No other code in the function is executed after a `return` statement. That is why there is no `return None` in this case.

Comment: Ok. I understand perfectly sir. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You also made an indention error in `def(congrat_winner)`

The correct way is:

```
    def congrat_winner(the_winner, computer, human):

        if the_winner != TIE:
            print(the_winner, "won!\n")
        else:
            print("It's a tie!\n")

        if the_winner == computer:
            print("As I predicted, human, I am triumphant once more. \n" \
                  "Proof that computers are superior to humans in all regards.\n")

        elif the_winner == human:
            print("No, no! It cannot be! Somehow you tricked me, human. \n" \
                  "But never again! I, the computer, so swears it\n!")

        elif the_winner == TIE:
            print("You were most lucky, human, and somehow managed to tie me. \n" \
                  "Celebrate today... for this is the best you will ever achieve.\n")
```

Moreover the last `elif` should be replaced with `else`:

```
    def congrat_winner(the_winner, computer, human):

        if the_winner != TIE:
            print(the_winner, "won!\n")
        else:
            print("It's a tie!\n")

        if the_winner == computer:
            print("As I predicted, human, I am triumphant once more. \n" \
                  "Proof that computers are superior to humans in all regards.\n")

        elif the_winner == human:
            print("No, no! It cannot be! Somehow you tricked me, human. \n" \
                  "But never again! I, the computer, so swears it\n!")

        else:
            print("You were most lucky, human, and somehow managed to tie me. \n" \
                  "Celebrate today... for this is the best you will ever achieve.\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Understand you already have your answer, but a piece of advice - try to test your functions in isolation.

In your case, you already had a hunch that there was an issue with your `winner` function. I've taken this directly from your question, where you mentioned "it won't return the winner".

There are plenty of approaches to testing but let's keep it simple and grab that function, copy it to a new python program, throw some game boards at it, and see what happens. I mean "see" literally - your best friend when it comes to testing is `print`. Say we modify your function like so:

```
def winner(board):
    print("winner function entered")
    WAYS_TO_WIN = ((0, 1, 2),
                   (3, 4, 5),
                   (6, 7, 8),
                   (0, 3, 6),
                   (1, 4, 7),
                   (2, 5, 8),
                   (0, 4, 8),
                   (2, 4, 6))

    for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
        print("for loop entered")
        if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != EMPTY:
            winner = board[row[0]]
            return winner

        if EMPTY not in board:
            return TIE
        return None
```

It may seem all too easy, but immediately we notice that in all cases the for loop is only ever entered once. Having a small section of code to focus on, it won't be too long before the indentation error is found.